# pm2 start -i max run on 12 vcpu buy my ec2 only has 8 vcpu

Tags: amazon-ec2, pm2

I just upgrade our AWS EC2 instance from `t2.xlarge` to `t2.2xlarge`, so our instance now has 8 vCPU. Upon restarting the server, I run the command  `pm2 start src/app.js -i max -f` and to my surprise, instead of my app running on 8vCPU, it now runs on 12 vCPU. At least that's what's the `pm2 list` displayed. What really happen here?

[image]

Here's the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

```
processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000038
cpu MHz         : 2300.118
cache size      : 46080 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 7
cpu cores       : 8
apicid          : 14
initial apicid  : 14
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov                 pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc                 rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x                2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_                lm abm cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid                 xsaveopt
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds                 swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips        : 4600.13
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Are you sure that's 12vCPUs and not just 12 threads/processes?

Comment: Please include the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @Maurice added the output

Comment: Actually I don't know what's that to be honest. But before this when my instance was t2.xlarge with 4vcpu, it lists only 4 app running when I run pm2 list. Hence I expect to have only have 8 app running now.

Comment: As you can see from `cpu cores       : 8` - the instance has 8 vCPUs, that means pm2 seems to be doing something wrong when it tries to find out the CPU count.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, you can just say `pm2 start src/app.js -i 8 -f` to bypass the automatic CPU detection.

Comment: I tried running `pm2 start src/app.js -i 8 -f` but somehow the list will still display the process is running on 12 vCpu/threads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229355/discussion-between-maurice-and-imin).

Answer (score 1):

Summary of what we talked about in the comments.

The output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` tells us, that the instance actually has 8 CPU cores, which we can see from this line:

```
cpu cores       : 8
```

That tells us AWS is giving you what you're paying for :-)

I don't know anything about pm2, but the [docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) tell me, that `-i max` in `pm2 start src/app.js -i max -f` tells pm2 to start as many worker processes as there are CPU cores.

It seems that somehow the CPU core detection has been messed up when you changed the instance type and it has chosen to add the new 8 cores to the 4 cores it already knew about to now give you 12 processes.

As a workaround you can explicitly set the number of worker processes to 8 like this:

```
pm2 start src/app.js -i 8 -f
```